# Merge Function with Range and Cells

Tags: excel, vba, merge, range, cell

I am trying to merge cells in a loop:

`WS1.Range(.Cells(2, 2 + ((i - 1) * 9)), .Cells(2, 2 + ((i - 1) * 9) + 5)).Merge`

but is not working; what is the correct way to do that?

Comment: I just did `ActiveSheet.Range("C1", "D5").Merge` and `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B5").Merge` and both worked. What's your error message?

Comment: "compile error: invalid or unqualified reference"

Comment: I have solved using "WS1." before "Cells"; it seems I have to declare every time the worksheet name.

Comment: `.Cells` requires a `With` statement. Do you have one?

Comment: I solved using the syntax worksheetname.cells and it worked, thnaks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WS1.Range(WS1.Cells(2, 2 + ((i - 1) * 9)), WS1.Cells(2, 2 + ((i - 1) * 9) + 5)).Merge
```

Comment: Alternatively - You can `Resize` the column from the first cell: `WS1.Cells(2, 2 + ((i - 1) * 9)).Resize(, 6).Merge`